# Take part of a string in C99

Tags: string

I need your help. I can't take a part of a string.

Let me give you some examples:

```
1234567890qwerty=filename.exe 1234567890qwerty
1234567890qwerty="filename.vbs"1234567890qwerty
1234567890qwerty = filename.vbs1234567890qwerty
1234567890qwerty  =  "filename.exe"  1234567890qwerty
1234567890qwerty=filename.exe 1234567890qwerty
1234567890qwerty="filename.vbs"1234567890qwerty
1234567890qwerty = filename.vbs1234567890qwerty
1234567890qwerty  =  "filename.exe"  1234567890qwerty
1234567890qwerty=filename.exe 1234567890qwerty
1234567890qwerty="filename.vbs"1234567890qwerty
1234567890qwerty = filename.vbs1234567890qwerty
1234567890qwerty  =  "filename.exe"  1234567890qwerty
```

I must have **filename.exe** and **filename.vbs**

The syntax that interests me is this:

1) there must be an equal;

2) there may or may not be of the spaces;

3) there may or may not be of the quotes;

4) there must be the name of a delimited file from .exe or .vbs;

Note: **1234567890qwerty** indicates any type of string.

Comment: regex is your friend ... add your attempt and then we'll help you to fix it

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow! as it's your first question it is important that you know that we're here to help, not to do your homework. Please, update your question with your own attempt at trying to solve this problem and other users will give your feedback on improving that to solve your problem. When you find that one answer satisfy you, please press the check mark on the side of that answer. Have fun.

Comment: You can try something like this ... `.*[\\s]*=[\\s]*[\"]{0,1}(filename\\.(?:exe|vbs))[\"]{0,1}[\\s]*.*`